# HMAC_GOST341194 value mismatch

Tags: c++, cryptography, hmac

I'm not sure that this place is right choise for that kind of issues(it's rather crypto related), but there is no other hope to spot error, unfortunately.

So, here is the code that I use to compute HMAC_GOST341194:

```
HMAC hmac;
string step1, step2, step3;

ipad.assign(blockSize, 0x36);
opad.assign(blockSize, 0x5c);

for (size_t i = 0uL, e = length; i < e; ++i) 
{
    ipad.replace(i, 1, 1, secret[i] ^ 0x36);
    opad.replace(i, 1, 1, secret[i] ^ 0x5c);
}

step1 = ipad + text;

hmac.hash(step1, step1.length(), step2);

step3 = opad + step2;

hmac.hash(step3, step3.length(), mac);
```

Hash function was double checked - there are no errors and all the test values are equal with other sources.

My block size is 256.

I use following S-boxes(CryptoPro Param Set):

```
const unsigned char S[8][16] = {
    { 10,   4,  5,  6,  8,  1,  3,  7,  13, 12, 14, 0,  9,  2,  11, 15  },
    { 5,    15, 4,  0,  2,  13, 11, 9,  1,  7,  6,  3,  12, 14, 10, 8   },
    { 7,    15, 12, 14, 9,  4,  1,  0,  3,  11, 5,  2,  6,  10, 8,  13  },
    { 4,    10, 7,  12, 0,  15, 2,  8,  14, 1,  6,  5,  13, 11, 9,  3   },
    { 7,    6,  4,  11, 9,  12, 2,  10, 1,  8,  0,  14, 15, 13, 3,  5   },
    { 7,    6,  2,  4,  13, 9,  15, 0,  10, 1,  5,  11, 8,  14, 12, 3   },
    { 13,   14, 4,  1,  7,  0,  5,  10, 3,  12, 8,  15, 6,  2,  9,  11  },
    { 1,    3,  10, 9,  5,  11, 4,  15, 8,  6,  7,  14, 13, 0,  2,  12  },
};
```

Here is what I have as an example(the only sample found):

```
K(ASCII) = "s=, ehesttgiyga bnss esi2leh3 mT"
K(in hex) = 733d2c20 65686573 74746769 79676120
626e7373 20657369 326c6568 33206d54 (32 bytes)

text (ASCII) = "This is message, length=32 bytes"
text (in hex) = 54686973 20697320 6D657373 6167652C
206C656E 6774683D 33322062 79746573

HMAC_GOSTR3411 = 4ff66c94 bddaae61 13360514 2b582b9c
0f38bbdf f3d7f0ee 6a9c935d 92bfa107
```

However, my value is: `C0F2FE71C3CA016356722646308B69453BB4CD1E232231E04BEB03DB6976F128`

Any help of providing more test data or either reject/verify existing will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer for this question: the example is incorrect, but there was a bug in my code either.

So, assuming

```
K(ASCII) = "s=, ehesttgiyga bnss esi2leh3 mT" 
text (ASCII) = "This is message, length=32 bytes"
```

1. [ipad || text](http://pastebin.com/5s4Ckd9s) hash is: `E9D755A47F72A558AE5E75F5B141F5B174E7B1FED281436F3FE835D78D0D9F05`
2. [opad || hash(ipad || text)](http://pastebin.com/g84h6B5K) hash is: `8FF55DDAAB167A22DE98286F10458A1619BC45C88F6EAC9CE947ED3FFB348822`

Second value is the HMAC_GOST341194 itself.

All hashes was computed using my code and verified using [cpverify](https://www.cryptopro.ru/sites/default/files/public/cpverify.exe) with params `cpverify.exe -mk -alg GR3411 "%YOUR_PATH_TO_FILE%\hash.txt"
PAUSE`

Hope this will help someone save couple hours of time not to research why the example HMAC is computed incorrectly [here](https://www.cryptopro.ru/sites/default/files/products/ipsec/rus-gost-ike.pdf).

PoC is available [here](https://gist.github.com/im-infamou5/c478431ad00e5857bfff).

Comment: You can by now accept your own answer, upvoted, thanks for the feedback